# cGAN train function problem with training strategy

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tf.keras, generative-adversarial-network

The code is as follows:
The Earlystopping and metric initilization and training step function:

```py
# Metrics initialization:
acc = ks.metrics.MeanSquaredError()
acc_ = ks.metrics.MeanSquaredError()
history:dict = {'loss':[],'acc':[], 'val_loss':[],'val_acc':[]}
# Don't bother this line of code:
max_step:int = len(train_data)//32
# Earlystopping implementation
global max_batch_patience,patience
breakpoint:int = 2
max_epochs:int = 10
patience:int = 1
max_batch_patience:list = []

def train_step(X, y, gen, disc, loss_fn, optimizer):
    X_gray, clues = X
    X_tr = y
    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape,tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
        pred = gen([X_gray,clues], training=True)
        loss = loss_fn(X_tr, pred)
        disc_pred = disc([X_gray], training=True)
        disc_loss = loss_fn(X_tr, disc_pred)
    grads = gen_tape.gradient(loss, gen.trainable_variables)
    gen.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, gen.trainable_variables))
    disc_grads = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, disc.trainable_variables)
    disc.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(disc_grads, disc.trainable_variables))
```

I want to know whether have i written the train step correctly or not!
The purpose of this model is to take GrayScale images with some (y_tr ,y_test one-hot-encoded labels) clues to generate colorized images.

```py
(X_tr,y_tr),(X_test,y_test) = ks.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

X_tr = X_tr.astype(np.float32)/255
X_test = X_test.astype(np.float32)/255

X_tr = X_tr.reshape(-1,32,32,3)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1,32,32,3)

X_tr_gray = np.array([cv2.cvtColor(x,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) for x in X_tr])
X_test_gray = np.array([cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) for x in X_test])

X_tr_gray = X_tr_gray.reshape(-1,32,32,1)
X_test_gray = X_test_gray.reshape(-1,32,32,1)



# Task 2, Build a conditional GAN aka cGAN to colorize the cifar10 dataset!

def cgan_layer(num_ch:int,
               num_filters:int,
               kernel_size:int|tuple,
               strides:int|tuple,
               drop:float,
               kernel_init:str='he_normal',
               bn:bool=False):

    model = ks.models.Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(num_filters,kernel_size,strides,padding='same',kernel_initializer=kernel_init,\
                     activation=lambda T:tf.nn.leaky_relu(T,0.3)))
    model.add(Dropout(drop))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(num_filters,kernel_size,strides,padding='same',kernel_initializer=kernel_init,\
                     activation=lambda T:tf.nn.leaky_relu(T,0.3)))
    model.add(Dropout(drop))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(Conv2D(num_ch,kernel_size,strides,padding='same',kernel_initializer=kernel_init,\
                     activation=lambda T:tf.nn.leaky_relu(T,0.3)))
    return model

lay = cgan_layer(3,64,5,1,0.5)



def cGAN_gen(in_shape:tuple,num_clues:tuple|int,embed_dims:tuple,concat_ax:int=-1,reshape_dim:int=256,num_channels:int=3)->ks.models.Model:
    in_layer = Input(shape=in_shape,dtype=tf.float32)
    clue_dim = Input(shape=num_clues,dtype=tf.float32)

    clue_embd = Embedding(embed_dims[0],embed_dims[1],dtype=tf.float32)(clue_dim)
    clue_embd = Flatten()(clue_embd)


    X = cgan_layer(32,32,5,1,0.5)(in_layer)
    X = cgan_layer(32,32,5,1,0.5)(X)
    X = cgan_layer(64,64,5,1,0.5)(X)
    X = cgan_layer(64,64,5,1,0.5)(X)

    X = Flatten()(X)

    Con = Concatenate(axis=concat_ax)([X,clue_embd])

    Resh = Dense(reshape_dim*in_shape[0]*in_shape[1],activation=lambda T:tf.nn.leaky_relu(T,0.3))(Con)
    Resh = Reshape((in_shape[0],in_shape[1],reshape_dim))(Resh)
    # print(Resh.shape)
    X = Conv2D(num_channels,1,1,padding='same',kernel_initializer='he_normal',\
                     activation=lambda T:tf.nn.tanh(T))(Resh)

    return ks.models.Model([in_layer,clue_dim],X)

def cGAN_disc(in_shape:tuple,num_filters:tuple,kernel_size:int|tuple,process_dims:tuple,\
                  kernel_init:str='he_normal',dr:float=0.5):

    in_layer = Input(shape=in_shape,dtype=tf.float32)

    X = Conv2D(num_filters[0],kernel_size,1,padding='same',kernel_initializer=kernel_init,\
                     activation=lambda T:tf.nn.leaky_relu(T,0.3))(in_layer)
    X = Dropout(dr)(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Conv2D(num_filters[1],kernel_size,1,padding='same',kernel_initializer=kernel_init,\
                     activation=lambda T:tf.nn.leaky_relu(T,0.3))(X)
    X = Dropout(dr)(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Conv2D(num_filters[2],kernel_size,1,padding='same',kernel_initializer=kernel_init,\
                     activation=lambda T:tf.nn.leaky_relu(T,0.3))(X)
    X = Dropout(dr)(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)

    F = Flatten()(X)

    X = Dense(process_dims[0],activation=lambda T:tf.nn.leaky_relu(T,0.3))(F)
    X = Dropout(dr)(X)
    X = Dense(process_dims[1],activation=lambda T:tf.nn.leaky_relu(T,0.3))(X)

    L = Dense(1,activation=lambda T:tf.nn.sigmoid(T))(X)

    return ks.models.Model(in_layer,L)

gen = cGAN_gen(in_shape=(32,32,1),num_clues=10,embed_dims=(10,10),concat_ax=1,reshape_dim=2,num_channels=3)
disc = cGAN_disc((32,32,3),(64,128,256),5,(256,128))

for x in disc.layers:
    print(x.output_shape)

for x in gen.layers:
    print(x.output_shape)

gen.summary()

disc.summary()

# checking if the models react as i expected 
disc(tf.random.normal((32,32,32,3),dtype=tf.float32))

gen([tf.random.normal((32,32,32,1)),tf.random.uniform(shape=(32,10),minval=0,maxval=10)])
#                            b  h  w  c                            b embd_dim



y_tr = np.array([tf.one_hot(x,10) for x in y_tr])
y_test = np.array([tf.one_hot(x,10) for x in y_test])

# checking the shape of the data
X_tr_gray.shape,y_tr.shape,X_tr.shape

train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((X_tr_gray,y_tr),X_tr)).shuffle(3000).batch(32).repeat(6)

test_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((X_test_gray,y_test),X_test)).batch(32)

train_data = train_data.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

test_data = test_data.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

I'd appreciate any aid

Comment: What happens when you try to run it? What is your problem with it? In my experience, my cGANs took something like 4 days to train and apparently suffered from mode collapse (i.e. all the images were the same!). It was almost certainly to do with the size and distribution of my dataset, though (I shouldn't have been so surprised at the "mode collapse").

Comment: The problem is that i don't know the way that i should train the model with the training data in an adversarial way!